# BottomSheetBehavior is not work when design library update to 24.2.0

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottom-sheet

BottomSheetBehavior work properly in

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
```

but when I update it to 24.2.0,it is not work.Is that a bug?
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/llScroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/blue_1"
        app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">
    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: 'not work' is not enough information to go off of. *How* does it not work?

Comment: I have the same problem. "Not work" means it just shows up as a simple layout without any expected behaviour, 

 mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED); do not work anymore. IT JUST DOES NOT WORK.

Comment: Same problem here .. Now it just shows up even when peekheight is not set. Thanks google!

Comment: It is not working after updating to 24.2.0

Comment: I just want to specify that the problem is with the app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior" type of BottomSheets and not with BottomSheet fragments.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**STATE_COLLAPSED : Hides a part of the bottom sheet**

**STATE_HIDDEN : Hides complete bottom sheet**

In Support Library 24.2.0, you have to set the peek height to indicate how many pixels you want your bottom sheet to show when collapsed.

So if you want it to be collapsed and hid, you can add the code like this after you initialized your BottomSheetBehavior:

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setPeekHeight(0);
```

that means when the bottom sheet collapsed, 0 pixel of its height will be shown.

Or your can just make it disappear if you need, use the code like this:

```
mBottomSheetBehavior.setHideable(true);
mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

Comment: I have not tried this yet, but i do not find anything in the revision history for bottomsheet: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: I found that the setPeekHeight(0) is the best and simplest way to get the old functionality back.

Answer (score 5):

**Updated August 30th, 2016**

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062055/3304388) explains the difference between `STATE_HIDDEN` and `STATE_COLLAPSED` and how to correctly use both in `com.android.support:design:24.2.0`.

**As of August 20th, 2016**

Although this does seem to be a bug with `com.android.support:design:24.2.0`, you can temporarily work around it by using `BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN`:

```
mBehavior.setHideable(true);
mBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_HIDDEN);
```

This will still close the bottom sheet with an animation.

I'm not sure what the actual difference between `STATE_COLLAPSED` and `STATE_HIDDEN` is, and the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomSheetBehavior.html#STATE_HIDDEN) is less than helpful, but until it's actually fixed I think `STATE_HIDDEN` is okay.

Comment: Works for me! Thanks!

Comment: it seems to me that "STATE_COLLAPSED" is triggered when peekheight > 0. Otherwise, "STATE_COLLAPSED" is omitted and "STATE_HIDDEN" triggers instead !!