# Android Design Support Library 24.2.1 makes BottomSheet open on startup

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-design-library, bottom-sheet

After switching to version 24.2.1 of the Android Design Support library from version 23.4.0 the *BottomSheetBehavior* stopped working for me. The BottomSheet shows as open and does not close when calling `setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)`. This does not happen on 23.4.0 of the Design library where BottomSheetBehaviour works for me as expected.

Did anything change in version 24 that requires using BottomSheetBehavior differently?

Here is my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:text="Open Bottom Sheet"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:text="Close Bottom Sheet"
        />

</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"/>
```

And here is the Activity code that I am using:

```
public class ScrollingActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private View m_bottomSheet;
private BottomSheetBehavior m_behaviour;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scrolling);

    m_bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
    m_behaviour = BottomSheetBehavior.from(m_bottomSheet);


    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(this);
    ((Button)findViewById(R.id.close_button)).setOnClickListener(this);
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.button:
            m_behaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
            break;
        case R.id.close_button:
            m_behaviour.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39030742/bottomsheetbehavior-is-not-work-when-design-library-update-to-24-2-0

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
m_behaviour.setPeekHeight(0);
```

It defaults to the "peek" state, so if you don't want it to peek at all, you need to set the peek height to 0.

Comment: Thanks, Scott. It worked as intended when setting m_behaviour.setPeekHeight(0) initially, e.g. in onCreate()

Answer (score 2):

```
 app:behavior_peekHeight="0dp"
 app:layout_behavior="@string/bottom_sheet_behavior"
```

You can set the peek height to 0dp in the layout, not need to set it programmatically