# How can I dim the background when Bottomsheet is displayed, without using Dialog?

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I know `BottomSheetDialog` does so already, but I need to use the regular `BottomSheet` and behavior generated from `BottomSheetBehavior.from()`. This `BottomSheet` doesn't dim the background and also touch outside would not close it. Is there a way to dim the background when `BottomSheet` is displayed? and maybe dismiss when touch outside. Basically the behavior just like `BottomSheetDialog` but I must use `BottomSheet` `BottomSheetBehavior` directly.

Comment: Why must you use `BottomSheetBehavior`?

Comment: Had the same problem. For me the reason to use `BottomSheet` and `BottomSheetBehavior` instead of `BottomSheetDialog(Fragment)` is that the `BottomSheet` plays nice when showing the keyboard. Using `BottomSheetDialogFragment` causes some janky animation. When showing the keyboard the DialogFragment just "snapps" to it's new position. BottomSheet animates smoothly up/down.

Comment: This has background dimming without fragment http://www.hidroh.com/2016/06/17/bottom-sheet-everything/

Answer (score 52, accepted):

**You can use this code**
1. MainActivity.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="24dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>

<View
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:id="@+id/bg"
    android:background="#99000000"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_light"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="aefwea"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

2. MAinActivity.java

   ```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

   private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
   private BottomSheetBehavior mBottomSheetBehavior;
   View bottomSheet;
   View mViewBg;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       bottomSheet = findViewById(R.id.bottom_sheet);
       mViewBg = findViewById(R.id.mViewBg);
       Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_1);
       button1.setOnClickListener(this);
       mViewBg.setOnClickListener(this);
       mBottomSheetBehavior = BottomSheetBehavior.from(bottomSheet);
       mBottomSheetBehavior.setBottomSheetCallback(new BottomSheetBehavior.BottomSheetCallback() {
           @Override
           public void onStateChanged(@NonNull View bottomSheet, int newState) {
               if (newState == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED)
                   mViewBg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
           }

           @Override
           public void onSlide(@NonNull View bottomSheet, float slideOffset) {
               Log.d(TAG, "onSlide: slideOffset" + slideOffset + "");
              mViewBg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
               mViewBg.setAlpha(slideOffset);
           }
       });

   }


   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
       switch (v.getId()) {
           case R.id.button_1: {
               mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED);
               break;
           }
           case R.id.bg: {
               mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
               break;
           }
       }
   }


   @Override
   public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
       if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
           if (mBottomSheetBehavior.getState() == BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_EXPANDED) {
               Rect outRect = new Rect();
               bottomSheet.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect);
               if (!outRect.contains((int) event.getRawX(), (int) event.getRawY())) {
                   mBottomSheetBehavior.setState(BottomSheetBehavior.STATE_COLLAPSED);
                   return true;
               }

           }
       }
       return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
   }

   }
   ```

Comment: I had to use `setPeekHeight(int peekHeight)` just as [this answer shows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39062055/370798) in order to make this example work

Comment: This works well! But isn't it bad for performance to repeatedly use findview? Especially in onSlide. Why not just obtain the reference to the view in oncreate?

Comment: This is a more proper solution.

Comment: how can dim status bar color ?

Comment: Just use `addBottomSheetCallback` as `setBottomSheetCallback` is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom fragment that has layout (kind of bottomSheet) attached to bottom and make the background `transparent_black` & when touching on that BG remove that fragment. Ex :

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ff2020"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.jiffysoftwaresolutions.copypastesampleapp.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/show"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Show" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomSheetFragment bottomSheetFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        findViewById(R.id.show).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (bottomSheetFragment == null) {
                    bottomSheetFragment = new BottomSheetFragment();
                }
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.bottom_sheet_fragment_container, bottomSheetFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

            }
        });

    }


    public void removeBottomSheet() {
        try {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(bottomSheetFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

}
```

**BottomSheetFragment.java**

```
public class BottomSheetFragment extends Fragment {


    private View rootView;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout, container, false);
        rootView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // remove sheet on BG touch
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).removeBottomSheet();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

}
```

**bottom_sheet_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#6d000000"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="5dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button1"
            android:textColor="#000" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button2"
            android:textColor="#000" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

To Add that fragment with bottom_top/animation.. you can follow this link : [Android Fragments and animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817900/android-fragments-and-animation)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Interface - onSlide which as a parameter slideOffSet of type float , can be used to dim the background. The new offset of this bottom sheet within [-1,1] range. Offset increases as this bottom sheet is moving upward. From 0 to 1 the sheet is between collapsed and expanded states and from -1 to 0 it is between hidden and collapsed states.

```
if ( slideOffSet>=0 && slideOffSet<=1 ) {
    mainActivityLayoutView.setAlpha( 1f - slideOffSet ); 
}
```

where mainActivityLayoutView is the id for NestedScrollView , holding the main contents of the activity.

Comment: doesn't look "dimmed"

Answer (score 0):

You can use my concept if you want that i used in [AlertDialog with Blur background in possition center](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40421723/5188159)

My approach

1. Take a screen shot
2. Programtically animate dim/blur screen shot
3. Get currant window using a dialog witch does not have any content
4. Attach screen shot with effect
5. Display real view i wanted to display

Here i have a class for take an image of the background as a bitmap

```
public class AppUtils {

    public static Bitmap takeScreenShot(Activity activity) {
        View view = activity.getWindow().getDecorView();
        view.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        view.buildDrawingCache();


        Bitmap b1 = view.getDrawingCache();
        Rect frame = new Rect();
        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(frame);
        int statusBarHeight = frame.top;

        Display display = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int width = size.x;
        int height = size.y;


        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(b1, 0, statusBarHeight, width, height - statusBarHeight);
        view.destroyDrawingCache();
        return b;
    }
}
```

Congrats now you have a darken/dim image  same as your background

Then your requirement is to dim not blur like mine so you can pass this bitmap to below method,

```
public static Bitmap changeBitmapContrastBrightness(Bitmap bmp, float contrast, float brightness) {
        ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix(new float[]
                {
                        contrast, 0, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, contrast, 0, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, contrast, 0, brightness,
                        0, 0, 0, 1, 0
                });

        Bitmap ret = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(ret);

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, paint);

        return ret;
    }
```

Now use a fake dialog / dialog withOut a background/content only to get the window (Check my questions implementation you can understand that )

```
Window window = fakeDialogUseToGetWindowForBlurEffect.getWindow();
window.setBackgroundDrawable(draw);  // draw is bitmap that you created
```

after this you can show your real view.In my case i display an alert you can display whatever your view and remember to remove/gone that alert when your real view goes out from the screen!

**Quick out put** : (background can be customized as you want,not only dim)

[image]

Comment: haha that's smart

Answer (score 0):

Use this style and apply to your dialog.

> PS: this style also works perfectly in Android 6.0, 6.1 and 7.0.

```
<style name="MaterialDialogSheet" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/MaterialDialogSheetAnimation</item>
    </style>
<style name="MaterialDialogSheetAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/popup_show</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/popup_hide</item>
    </style>
```

And use as:

```
final Dialog mBottomSheetDialog = new Dialog(mActivity, R.style.MaterialDialogSheet);
```

Thanks.

Comment: @tir38 don't judge anyone without knowing an issue.
they mentioned without using Fragment Dialog.
you better answer that question without downvoting other's answer.

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me...!

Comment: Could you share the animations XML and style as well?

Answer (score 0):

In case the view implementing the `BottomSheetBehavior` is inside a distinct activity you can use the following solution

For making the background of your activity transparent + dimmed add following style to your activity

```
<style name="Your.Transparent.Style">
    <!-- Found no solution for setting the status bar color to fully transparent 
         from within the style. Had to resort to programmatically setting -->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
</style>
```

Inside your AndroidManifest.xml set the activity theme

```
<activity
   android:name="your.activity"
   android:theme="@style/Your.Transparent.Style" />
```

Setting the status bar color to fully transparent (only working for API >= 21)

```
// Inside your activity's onCreate 
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setStatusBarTransparent(window)

fun setStatusBarTransparent(window: Window) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS)
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS)
        window.statusBarColor = Color.TRANSPARENT
    }
}
```

And finally for hiding the bottom sheet when clicking outside of sheet content, extend the `BottomSheetBehavior`

```
class AutoCloseBottomSheetBehavior<V : View>(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet
) : BottomSheetBehavior<V>(context, attrs) {
    
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    override fun onLayoutChild(parent: CoordinatorLayout, child: V, layoutDirection: Int): Boolean {
        parent.setOnTouchListener { _, event ->
            if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                val outRect = Rect()
                child.getGlobalVisibleRect(outRect)
                if (!outRect.contains(event.rawX.toInt(), event.rawY.toInt())) {
                    state = STATE_HIDDEN
                    return@setOnTouchListener true
                }
            }

            return@setOnTouchListener false

        }
        return super.onLayoutChild(parent, child, layoutDirection)
    }
}
```

And set it for your view's behavior

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <Your.View.Acting.As.BottomSheet
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior=".your.path.AutoCloseBottomSheetBehavior" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```